# Credit debit and balance of a customer in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, accounting

I'm working on a Point of Sale System developing in Java, and for backend I am using a SQL Server database. As I'm new to database and confuse that I'm doing write in database.

For ever sale I'm making invoice, the table design is like that

1. `Invoice` table has columns `InvoiceID`, `InvoiceDate`, `CutomerID`, `MethodOfPayment`, `Comments`
2. `Line Item` table has columns `InvoiceID`, `LineitemNo`, `ProductID`, `QTY`, `Price`
3. `Transaction` table has columns `TransactionID`, `InvoiceID`, `Debit`, `Credit`, `Balance`, `InvoiceStatus`

Walking customers is always cash customers, so I have no problem with them. The `InvoiceStatus` flag will be close to them because no payment left from them.

For other customers they take material on credit also.

I need to to save there Credit Debit and Balance history in a very effective way.

My problem is that for every customer do I need separate table for record of there credit debit and balance history or all in one table, because in future the table size will grow very big if I use only one table.

Or if someone have better database design which I'm using now it will be very helpful.

Comment: Your question is unclear. you have described what your application does, but you haven't said what your specific problem is.

Comment: i edited my question basically i have problem in accounting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its recommended to make a separate table for the pending debits, and the the pending debits will be dynamic which means when ever the invoice collected completely the delete its record.
And your invoices table will be as its.

Comment: If the customer A have 4 pending invoices. of amount total $100 . let say $25 , each. he paid $60 . How can i delete the 3rd record because full payment of 3rd invoice didn't receive. 

Also i need the Credit Debit and Balance report in the end.

Comment: The payment will be according to invoice id so when ever the balances becomes 0 then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Some sample data might help us understand the problem a bit better.

if I try to read between the lines, you are asking whether it is better to have one record for each invoice which you update when the customer makes a payment, or whether you have a separate record for each payment associated with an invoice which you can then sum or manipulate as you wish. If that is correct then the answer is "it depends" on how granular your transactions need to be.

In my experience accounting packages should be as auditable as possible.

I would suggest that your transactions table have a separate record for each "transaction" where an invoice is a transaction, each payment is a transaction, etc. you could have a column for "transaction_type".

also you talk about having a "table for each customer" the answer to that is no.

Answer (score 0):

1. There will be an Invoice & Line Items table to record sales.
2. There will be a Receipts-Payment table to record payments
3. There will be customer table to store their balance (credit or debit)

So for every transaction (invoice or payment), you will update the balance in the customer table.